# Integrate SASS/SCSS on Ember Project with POD structure

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-less

I just want to ask what is the best approach to integrate `sass/scss` on ember project?

Currently my project is in `pod` structure and I just import `style.scss` on main `app.scss` under styles folder. 
Is it fine or there is a better approach?

```
--- app
---- pods
------- home
---------- template.hbs
---------- controller.js
---------- style.scss
---- styles
------- app.scss
```

Then in `app.scss` styles imported look like this

```
@import "./app/pods/home/style.scss";
```

Comment: Hey, Chael. Are you working on a fresh project - or an older project?

Comment: @sheriffderek actually on fresh project, but still I want to know how too on older project

Comment: Well, given that it's a new project - you may want to double check if pods is a good idea. There has been this rumored 'module unification' that might happen in the future - that was meant to replace the ideas behind 'pods' - and I'm not sure if using pods is recommended anymore. Maybe ask in the ember discord channel or something. I did see some addons when I searched 'pods and sass'

Comment: @sheriffderek Thanks, I'll check that.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used pods in years - because (*like expecting controllers to be removed*) - I was told that there was going to be a new file layout system. Since hearing that / I've heard bits and pieces of conversation that lead me to believe that *pods* aren't really a go-to for new projects.

*That being said*, I share your desire to have a nice file structure. I'd love to 'drag' a folder from one project to another / and just have all the parts of the component copy over.

Since we have the app.scss - (you said you're using sass) - / that kinda acts as the index.

I include resets and mixins and a bunch of stuff for setup. - so, that's not really podish... and maybe there are 'page' level kinda layout... which doesn't really fit either... - so, what it comes down to is really 'components', right?

[ember-component-css](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-component-css) is pretty cool - but it also has some opinions that could clash.

There's this - https://github.com/justtal/ember-cli-sass-pods - but it's 4 years old / (but so are pods) - so, it might still work great.

Because there isn't a really clear path here... I just create a component folder in `styles/components/component-name.styl` - and then in my `styles/components.styl` I `@import 'component-name.styl` - and then in my `app.styl` I import the components...

In my case / I actually *like* to use the cascade - and I need the files to all to be combined - in order. I can't have some of it in the vendor file.

It's not ideal (just because I have to create each file explicitly and register it) - but I can't afford to just keep wishing there was a better file layout.

Instead of fuzzy searching `component-name > template`

I just search `template > component-name`

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

I wonder which style will cause me less pain in future transitions. They'll offer codemods to help / but they can't account for unique configurations.

I'd suggest asking this in the official discuss forum. You'll get the real answers there. : )

https://discuss.emberjs.com/

Comment: There was a recent update on the status of module unification which is the new file system layout you are talking about: https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/03/11/update-on-module-unification-and-octane.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `app/styles` directory, is the home for stylesheets like CSS, SASS, or LESS.
2. Folders like `vendor` and `public` that can also hold many other files of the `developer's choice`.
3. So in your case if you wish to have separate `scss` file for each `pod`,

   - you can put it in the place as you mentioned. **(else)**
   - have it under `app/styles/pod1.scss` and import it under `.ember-cli-build.js` -> `app.import('app/styles/pod1.scss')`

**[References]**

You can get the detailed view of Project layouts, Stylesheet compilation, Assets and dependencies below

1. [Project layouts](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/project-layouts/)
2. [Stylesheet compilation](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/stylesheets/)
3. [Assets and dependencies](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/assets-and-dependencies/)

Comment: That's going to add all the app.imported styles to vendor.css

Answer (score 0):

Besides `ember-component-css` there is `ember-css-modules`.
Both addons try to achieve about the same goal, however I *really* prefer `ember-css-modules`.

That addon has an addon called `ember-css-modules-sass`. Both together will easily allow you to write one sass file per component.

You just place a `styles.scss` file in your component pod (`app/components/my-component/styles.scss` and then use `local-class="my-class"`  instead of `class="my-class"` in your template.

Your classes in your `scss` will be automatically namespaces.